# Is there a way to upload a html document and render it in VueJs?

Tags: html, vue.js

I have html documents tha I need to render in my front end(Vue.Js). What I want to achieve is that I should be able to fetch the html doc from my database and render it in Front end. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to display the html content in vue js application

> If you use double mustache

```
<span> {{ htmlContent }} </span>
```

the html content will not get parsed by the browser, it will be a raw string

> If you use v-html directive

```
<span v-html="rawHtml"></span>
```

All the html content will be displayed in the UI

Comment: As explained in the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML).
Especially note their warning that you should only load trusted html (which OP seems to be doing, but worth mentioning in the answer):

"Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS vulnerabilities. Only use HTML interpolation on trusted content and never on user-provided content."

Comment: @chans the method you showed is for raw html. What I will be getting is base64 encoded data that has to be decoded first in html format

Answer (score 0):

@Chans the method you showed as I said was to render HTML Document. But I should have been more clear in my question and your answer is correct based on the question I asked, but if anyone is trying to do the same thing i.e trying to fetch base64 encoded data (Html) from the database and wants to render it on  Front End, You need to first decode the data (atob). I hope this helps someone.